# Reading a file using fgetc is giving extra (garbage) values

Tags: c

I have created a function to read data from a text file. The function reads data into a buffer and then copies it into a separate variable as the buffer gets filled.

I noticed that the *line_size* (see reference below) variable is overstepping the actual size of the line i.e the value of *line_size* is 106 while the actual length of my line is 103 characters.

So to debug, I added a print statement which corresponded each character read to the current buffer size: `printf("%c\t%i\n",c,current_buffer_size);`

Once I ran the program, turns out that **fgetc** is reading some 'garbage' characters (see screenshot below).

*(reference: **char *line** stores data from the buffer, **int line_size** keeps track of the size of char *line )*

**Note**: the value of `FILE_BUFFER` is 128

[image]

```
char *readline(FILE *fptr)
{
  char buffer[FILE_BUFFER];
  char *line = malloc(sizeof(char));
  int current_buffer_size, line_size = 0;
  int c;
  int is_reading = 1;

  while(is_reading)
  {
    current_buffer_size = 0;
    while(current_buffer_size < FILE_BUFFER)
    {
      c = fgetc(fptr);
      if ( c == '\n' || feof(fptr))
      {
        is_reading = 0;
        break;
      }
      buffer[current_buffer_size] = c;
      current_buffer_size += 1;
      printf("%c\t%i\n",c,current_buffer_size);
    }
    line_size += current_buffer_size;
    line = (char *) realloc(line,line_size*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(&line[line_size-current_buffer_size], buffer, current_buffer_size);
  }
  if (line_size == 0) return NULL;
  line = (char *) realloc(line,(line_size+1)*sizeof(char));
  line[line_size] = 0;
  printf("\n%i\n",line_size); // final size of the line
  return line;
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Try printing out the hexadecimal values of those "garbage" characters.  (Two of them might be `0A` and `0D`)

Comment: @Tau the values are `e2 80 8e` in that order

Comment: The hex bytes 0xE2 0x80 0x8E are UTF-8 encoding for U+200E, which is a punctuation character.  In fact, U+200E is LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK, abbreviated LRM and distinct from U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK or RLM.  If your terminal is running in UTF-8 mode, you can't print any of the bytes from 0x80 .. 0xFF on their own.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler once the loop breaks, it reallocates space with 1 extra byte for the string terminator character, so no issue there. `FILE_BUFFER` Is 128.

Comment: I think the data is in your file. I tried [running your code on ideone](https://ideone.com/oLZHRT), it ran perfectly fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight when I output the file using `cat myfile.txt` , it does not show those characters

Comment: The problem is nothing that I raised as possibilities in my first (now-deleted) comment (though I think you should look at `line_size` carefully — I have not yet done so, but …).  The trouble is purely and simply that the data you're reading is UTF-8 encoded, so you cannot reliably print single bytes `c` where `(c & 0x80) == 0x80`.

Comment: Given what **Jonathan Leffler** stated, it seems as if you have some mixed languages in your text file.  Does said text file include any right-to-left text, such as Hebrew or Arabic?

Comment: @talha That's because `cat` does not show the left-to-right mark. Run a binary dump on your file to see the extra characters.

Comment: Note that you have a leak in `if (line_size == 0) return NULL;` — you need to `free(line)` before returning that way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight a hex-dump shows some missing characters https://i.imgur.com/Pqz8yrv.png . My text editor did not pick up on these characters either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the answer has been posted, thank you.

Comment: `feof(fptr)` is not what you'd want to do - compare `c` against `EOF` instead. There are 2 conditions that will return `EOF` - end of file *or* an error... you're breaking on only one here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala noted, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your helpful comments. The issued has been resolved thanks to @JonathanLeffler and @dasblinkenlight

So the problem appeared to be that some characters in the file were falling out of the single byte UTF-8 range (0-127). Since my text editor and terminal are both running in this UTF-8 mode, these characters were not displayed. A binary dump of each character (using `xxd -b -c2 file.txt`) revealed this problem. (Full disclosure: the text file was exported from whatsapp).

**Memory dump** showing the out of range characters (left) and 'garbage values' (right)
[image] [image]

*(The three characters: `11100010` `10000000` `10001110` were causing trouble)*

This would also explain the other seemingly inexplicable memory errors the application was throwing due to the 'extra counting' of characters. A lot makes sense now.